# Python - Check if a word belongs

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need your help about a small program I'm making. 
The program checks if a word is True, False or invalid argument.
For example, I type `e_silaba(ALO)` and it verifies if the word is possible based on the letters in vowel.

- My first question is, do I have to choose the size of my string (word)?
- What better way do I have to see if the word doesn't belong to "vowel"? I know the way I made is wrong but I can't find a solution for that..
- The way I made to check if the word is true only verifies the first two positions and I don't think it's a good idea to spam and's all over the place. Is there a way to easily verify each position of the string one by one to check if it belongs to, in this case, "vowel".

vowel = ["A" , "E" , "I" , "O" , "U"]

```
def e_silaba(word):

   if word[0] in vogal or word[1] in vowel:
     return True
   elif word not in vowel:
     return False
   else:
     print "e_word:invalid argument"
```

Comment: `word not in vowel` checks whether `word` is (not) one of the one-letter strings in `vowel`. I don't think this is what you want, especially since any such word would already have been matched by `word[0] in vogal`, so the final `else:` clause can never be hit.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to verify that the word in question IS a word just by checking to see if it contains vowels, use this for loop:

```
for letter in word:
    if letter.upper() in vowel:
        return True
return False
```

This will check every letter in your word (regardless of length) to see if it is in your list vowel. Also note that it checks letter.upper(), which converts the letter to its uppercase version to accurately compare it to your uppercase vowel list. If it reaches the end of the word without having returned True, it means it did not encounter any vowels and will then return false.

Comment: better to call `.upper()` on word rather than on each character, also use `any` like `return any(letter in vowel for letter in word.upper())` and make `vowel` a `set` first for improved O(1) membership testing

Comment: @Chris_Rands Worth posting as an answer IMO

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to check if `word` contains only alphabetic characters you can use the `.isalpha()` method on it. As far as your function is concerned maybe you can solve it using sets like below:

```
vowels = set('aeoiu')
def e_silaba(word):
    if (set(word.lower()).issubset(vowels)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

What it does is first lowercase all the letters in `word` with the `.lower()` method, makes a set out of all characters in the new lower-cased word and checks if those characters are subset of the vowels set with the `.issubset()` method.

You also perhaps don't even need to make this function and explicitly return `True` or `False`. You can simply use `set(word.lower()).issubset(vowels)` which itself is a boolean expression that will return `True` or `False`.

Comment: I don't think there's much point making a set out of the letters in `word.lower()` if you're only going to check each of them (at most) once.

Comment: Having said all that, welcome to StackOverflow and don't be put off of answering :-)

Comment: You're right, i'm always for a better solution. And thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to put @Chris_Rands's excellent comment into an answer: The simplest way is to turn the list of vowels into a `set` and compare the letters in `word.lower()` against it using `any()`:

```
vowels = set("aeiou")
def e_silaba(word):
    return any(x in vowels for x in word.lower())
```

If you want to make sure the word is not entirely composed of vowels you can use this solution:

```
vowels = set("aeiou")
def e_silaba(word):
    if all(x in vowels for x in word.lower()):
        return False
    else:
        return any(x in vowels for x in word.lower())
```

This will exclude "a" and "i" which actually are words though. As one last example, if you only want to check that condition for words of at least two characters, use this:

```
vowels = set("aeiou")
def e_silaba(word):
    if len(word) > 1 and all(x in vowels for x in word.lower()):
        return False
    else:
        return any(x in vowels for x in word.lower())
```

Hopefully this is enough to illustrate how you could add more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
vowel=['A','E','I','O','U']
def e_silaba(word):
    word=word.upper()
    for i in vowel:
        try:
            word.index(i)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return False
```

Output will be

```
>>> e_silaba('sandeep')
True
>>> e_silaba('dp')
False
>>> e_silaba('lda')
True
>>> e_silaba('bcf')
False
>>>
```

Comment: Assuming there are often more letters in words than in the list of all possible vowels, it makes more sense to base the iteration over the letters in `word` than the letters in `vowels`.

Comment: @ArthurTacca : Sorry didn't get it . Can you give a example where the above code doesnt work ?

Comment: It doesn't not work, just less efficient / more confusing than one where the outer loop is over letters in the word. BTW I'm not the downvoter.